# The APNS Token Id is not generating for one iPhone device

Tags: ios

The APNS Token Id is not generating for one iPhone device  having UDID :  4C6B0B7*-****-****-****-36**********. But for other iPhone device it's working fine.

This device is one of our app. users device.Only for this device APNS token is getting null.

Comment: Do you get some error in `- application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps:

1. Generate a new provisioning profile with "push notification" entitlement enabled
2. Download the new provisioning profile and use it for development builds
3. check for error inside the overridden method "application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:"
4. Make sure to follow [apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html) for push notification